# How to use Autoinstall from Ubuntu 20.04 with virt-install command?

Tags: server, 20.04, system-installation, kvm-virtualization

I use Ubuntu 20.04 desktop as host to run different Linux VMs using KVM. The VMs are created in scripts using virt-install. This works well with CentOS VMs etc. Now I would like to install Ubuntu 20.04 VM using Autoinstall option. I have generated the Autoinstall file and use it now. Here is my current command:

```
virt-install --name ubuntu1 --vcpus 2 --memory 2048 --disk device=cdrom,path=./seed.iso --cdrom ~/images/ubuntu-20.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso --disk pool=default,size=10,bus=virtio --network network=br0 --os-variant ubuntu20.04
```

The installation starts but then I got the prompt to confirm the autoinstall option. I am aware, that I have to provide the autoinstall option to the kernel. But why? The option "--cdrom" does not work with the option "--extra-args". I have tried the option "--location" with the option "--install kernel=...,initrd=...,kernel_args", but it does not work. I would get another errors for missing boot path etc.

If I just confirm to continue with autoinstall, then the installation will be done well. So the error is not in the local user-data or meta-data on the created iso. I just need to find out the way to specify autoinstall option to the kernel on boot.

Has anybody got a working script with virt-install to start Autoinstall Ubuntu 20.04 installation?

I am aware, that there are examples with "kvm" command in Ubuntu documentation. But I would prefer to use virt-install for all my scripts and reuse the existing scripts.

Comment: Did you check --unattended option for virt-install?

Comment: If i just add "--unattended", I will get: the error
```
Starting install...
WARNING  Attempting unattended method=cdrom injection for a non-windows OS. If this doesn't work, try passing install media to --location
WARNING  Using unattended profile 'desktop'
ERROR    OS 'ubuntu20.04' does not support required injection method 'cdrom'
```

Comment: If I change --cdrom to --location, then I would  get another error:

    Starting install...
    WARNING  Using unattended profile 'desktop'
    ERROR    ubuntu20.04 requires the user-password to be set.
    Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
    If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
      virsh --connect qemu:///system start ubuntu8
    otherwise, please restart your installation.

Comment: You may want to chek https://www.x386.xyz/index.php/2021/01/06/kvm-on-ubuntu-server-1/ , looks like there are some working examples there.

Answer (score 3):

Somehow, the --location option cannot find the kernel and initrd for the Ubuntu image. You must provide the paths manually:

```
--location /var/lib/libvirt/images/ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso,kernel=casper/hwe-vmlinuz,initrd=casper/hwe-initrd
```

Below is a complete example that also enables logging via the serial console and prevents rebooting after the installation is complete:

```
virt-install \
-n test \
--description "Test" \
--os-type Linux \
--os-variant ubuntu20.04 \
--memory 2048 \
--vcpus 2 \
--disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/kubernetes.qcow2,bus=virtio,size=50 \
--disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/seed.iso,format=raw,cache=none \
--graphics none \
--network bridge:br0 \
--location /var/lib/libvirt/images/ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso,kernel=casper/hwe-vmlinuz,initrd=casper/hwe-initrd \
--noreboot \
--extra-args 'console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial autoinstall'
```